# Change value from SQL command output to match python syntax

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, asyncpg

I'm a newbie regarding SQL and PostgreSQL and database management, but I need a database for a discord bot I'm making. I'm using asyncpg to manage a database with python

Now, let's say I have a command which has to find if username already exists in that database:

```
try:
            with open("creds.json", "r") as file:  
                creds = json.load(file)
            print("\n" + "Connecting to database")    
            host = creds["DB_HOST"]
            user = creds["DB_USER"]
            password = creds["DB_TOKEN"]
            database = creds["DB_NAME"]
            conn = await asyncpg.connect(host=host, user=user, password=password, database=database)
            print("\n"+ f"PostgreSQL connection to database stablished successfully")
            exists = await conn.fetch('''
SELECT EXISTS (
SELECT 1 
FROM table 
WHERE username=($1)); 
''', str(discordusername#1234)) 
            await conn.close()  
            print("Query finished, connection to database closed")        
            print(exists)
```

It either returns True or False in this form `[<Record exists=False>] or [<Record exists=True>]`, so to check if its true or false I have to convert the 'exists' to a string and then compare it to either `[<Record exists=False>] or [<Record exists=False>]` as a string:

```
if str(exists) == "[<Record exists=False>]":
    ...
elif str(exists) == "[<Record exists=True>]"
    ...
```

Is there anyway to 'convert' `[<Record exists=False>]` to a plain False and `[<Record exists=False>]` to a plain True that Python can directly understand?

same goes when getting a value from a table, say, and int that have to be addressed the same way, returning, for example,

```
[<Record rowname=5>]
```

Comment: Best hint you will receive, use some ORM abstraction like sqlalchemy, DON'T write sql queries as strings plzzzzzz.

Comment: Uh. My actual problem is that I know this is the wrong way to adress it, but I don't know how to fix it as I know like, the very basic basis of SQL. Thanks anyway, I'll try sqlalchemy

Comment: have you tried bool(exists)? Most classes implement a method overload for those things

Comment: Since it’s just one value maybe `fetchval` would be better than `fetch`?

Comment: Okay, changing it to fetchval fixed it. WIth fetch, I changed to bool but the variable was still [<Record exists=True>]/[<Record exists=False>] (It didn't recognize the bool properly) when changing it to fetchval it worked, even without bool(). With fetchval it directly returns a Python boolean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetch()` returns list of records, one record for each returned row.

```py
    result = await conn.fetch(my_query)

    # print the value of column 'exists' of the first row (number 0)
    print(result[0]['exists'])
    
    # print the value of the first column of the first row
    print(result[0][0])
```

Read more about [asyncpg.Record](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/api/index.html#asyncpg.Record).